# Hazelcast mongodb integration; loadAll method

Tags: mongodb, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I was looking at the code for the integration of MongoDB with hazelcast on their github page.

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/mongodb/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/loader

The MongoMapStore implements a loadAll method which takes a Java Collection as its parameter. Later in the ReadWriteThroughCache.java code supplements.loadAll is called where supplements is an imap from what Ive understood so far this executes the loadAll method in MongoMapStore.java but where are we passing the Collection keys parameter. The mongoCollection is instantiated but how do we determine keys in that example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MapStore#loadAll(keys)` is called internally when Hazelcast maps are initialized. You do not need to provide any parameters, it is the set of distributed keys to all members in batches. Please see the details & steps of map initialization with persistence enabled here: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#initializing-map-on-startup

Comment: but what is the keys here.  and what is the parameter that should be passed to loadall method in MongoMapStore.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the excerpts from the documentation link provided above:

> Here is the MapLoader initialization flow:
>
> When getMap() is first called from any member, initialization will
>   start depending on the value of InitialLoadMode. If it is set to
>   EAGER, initialization starts on all partitions as soon as the map is
>   touched, i.e., all partitions will be loaded when getMap is called. If
>   it is set to LAZY, data will be loaded partition by partition, i.e.,
>   each partition will be loaded with its first touch.
>
> Hazelcast will call MapLoader.loadAllKeys() to get all your keys on
>   one of the members.
>
> That member will distribute keys to all other members in batches.
>
> Each member will load values of all its owned keys by calling
>   MapLoader.loadAll(keys).
>
> Each member puts its owned entries into the map by calling
>   IMap.putTransient(key,value).